# How to enable websocket on window server 2016 docker container

Tags: docker, websocket

We have a legacy application that uses WebSocket  protocol. We're in the process of modernizing it to docker container. The app was built in Asp.net MVC 4. I'm having issue establishing hand shake.

> ws://qrdevtest.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com:8080/ws.ashx?param=eBGR3niLY4D96vn2y6LP8YioQslOPtHgFJQbvkNXAulf0iElN3uPGHPq5/CAJS9X7pkl+OeKUBay3jnTa5klTHE+xp0Tjb21Jl5UtnmmeMjKJkNeDu1bvhNfBi0dpZXHu8lmig+HxuHtIOuaep6nCG7HCJCcllKYY2e9KY5WkRjEoj2DeBAPhgXspaWz9hlFyrl16lebtrCVwb+kKrq8F0orZLaZb9xq3D8FL8oDewA=

```
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fixed this error by installing WebSockets protocol from the container.

To access powershell from the container I used this command

```
docker exec -it {2 digit containerId} powershell
```

Then to enable websockets protocol

```
Add-WindowsFeature Web-WebSockets
```

To list all windows features

```
Get-windowsfeature
```

Comment: @Serenkiy happy to help!